# Restore auto renewable subscriptions

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

Am developing an iOS app which have auto renewable subscriptions. Normal purchase flow is working fine but am facing issue in restoring transactions.

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]
```

Am using this to restore transactions and Apple returns all the transactions made in my app. I dont know how to find exact transaction of the user and validate receipt. My app validate receipts by sending it to our server which sends to Apple and gets status.

Exact Scenario is:

1. User A installs app and buys subscription in device 1.
2. User A installs app in 2nd device and want to restore the subscription made in device 1. How to handle this scenario??

This question might seems duplicate but I haven't found the exact scenario am looking for.

Thanks..

Comment: What do you mean by "find exact transaction of user"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to restore all non-expired transactions. You should be able to determine this from the JSON you get when you verify the receipts with Apple. BTW @itdeeps, this validation scheme is not that recommended by Apple. Apple recommends either on-device validation iOS7) or validation on your server (iOS6 and earlier).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Sry I think I haven't mentioned it clearly. If I try to restore transactions then returned result contains transactions from all users  then how can I determine the exact one. For example, if User A, B and C subscribes and if User B is trying to use the subscription in another device then [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions] returns transactions of all users (A,B and C). How can be User B's subscription can be determined? Am I clear now? Sorry for my english :(

Comment: What do you mean by "user"? Apple ID?

Comment: Yes Chris. You can purchase subscription per user ID right??

Comment: I think the situation is simpler than this. The typical use-case is that you worry about one Apple Id. A restore will give you receipt(s) from a single Apple Id, ie, the one the person entered when given the Apple prompt that comes up after you invoke the restore.